# php function - selecting first item in returned array for each row

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a MySQL DB.  For each row of about 100 rows, I need the first item in a list of items inside a column in a table. So if the column in the first row contained

```
honda convertible four-wheel drive
```

I would need to pick off Honda. And if the next row and same column contained

```
mazda hardtop two-wheel drive
```

I would need to pick off mazda.

I was trying to do it in the ajax call, but am having issues with that since SELECT FIRST and SELECT TOP 1 are not supported by MySql.  So, perhaps a better solution would be to do it in the function that gets the data after the return. Since one of the items I am returning is all of the data in that particular column (in addition to other columns in the array). The column is selector_buttongroup_classes. Here is my function:

```
displayCars();

function displayCars () {

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '/modules/crm/selector-ajax.php',
        data : {
            'action' : 'get-images'
        },
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data) {
       var resultArray = data.isotopecubes;
       var resultArray2 = data.isotopecubes2;
       var selectorDiv = $('#boat_isotope_gallery');
       var divHtml = '';

          var i = 0;

          for (i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {

              divHtml +=  "<div class='element-item " + resultArray[i].selector_buttongroup_classes + "' data-range-test='100-400' " + resultArray[i].selector_sliderdata_attributes + " ><h3 class='name'>" + resultArray[i].product_name + "</h3><p class='weight'><img src='" + resultArray[i].photo + "' width='80' border='0' alt=''></p></div>"; 
          }

        selectorDiv.html(divHtml);
    },
    error : function(err) {
        console.log('ajax failure');
    }
});
} }); // end of document ready
```

How do I get something like

```
$manufacturer[i]=resultArray[i].selector_buttongroup_classes.first_item
```

that I can then use within the For statement?

Comment: MySQL has `ORDER BY column LIMIT 1` to get the first row of results.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. `TOP 1` is for getting the first row of results. But your question is about extracting the first word from a string, not getting the first row. You can do that with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` in MySQL, `explode()` in PHP, or `.split()` in Javascript.

Comment: @bksi He doesn't have an array, he just has a string that came from the database column.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i didn't get that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split a string on spaces:

```
var manufacturer = resultArray[i].selector_buttongroup_classes.split(' ')[0];
```

You can also do it in the MySQL query with the [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(selector_buttongroup_classes, ' ', 1) AS manufacturer
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b233/1)

Comment: The Select substring didn't work for me, but the first option with adding the split on the end worked perfectly:  var manufacturer = resultArray[i].selector_buttongroup_classes.split(' ')[0];  Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know why SUBSTRING_INDEX didn't work for  you. It works here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b233/1